# Why BoxColliders collision does not work?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Canvas, there are 2 images on it. I added BoxCollider 2D to the first image, and BoxCollider 2D and Rigidbody 2D to the second, and then I placed the second image above the first. I start the game, the image begins to fall, and passes through the first image. Moreover, if you set a different color for the second image, you can see that the second image passes over the first.
What is my mistake and how to fix it?

I need the second image to fall on the first and stay there.

Comment: Canvases dont use simulated physics like a regular object would in the inspector. If you were to remove your images from the canvas and placed them in world space, i think you'll find it may work as intended.

Comment: If I move the images and the camera outside the canvas, then these images are not visible on the camera. I move the camera and images off the canvas and put the image on the camera. That is, the image is displayed only on the canvas.

Comment: I solved my question, I don’t think that it will be useful to someone once, but I left the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I made sprites from images and placed them in world space, everything works as it should.